# Prevent user from entering certain word in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

so I have a site and I would like my users to not be able to words like ".com" or ".net" etc. If they do enter it then i just want it to replace with a space. So far I have toe javascript code for if users were to type in any html code into the text area, then it would replace it with a space, I want the same to to happen if they were to type out those certain words.

```
function stoppedTyping(){
    if(this.value.length > 0) { 
        document.getElementById('post_btn').disabled = false; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('post_btn').disabled = true;
    }

    var re = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
    for (i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(re, "");
    }
    var se = ".com";
    for(a=0; a < arguments.length; a++){
            arguments[a].value=arguments[a].value.replace(se, "");
    }
}
```

The last var se.... is my attempt to try and replace the word. But it isn't working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206613/detect-once-a-certain-word-has-just-been-entered-in-a-textarea

Comment: Try `.replace(/\.com/gi, "");` instead

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but this method seems not to have any arguments.  The iteration of arguments looks like doesn't execute.

Comment: @SidCool How do you know this function doesn't have any arguments? It all depends on what's passed to it.

Comment: @Ian My bad.  My Java experience shrouded my logic.  Even if the method doesn't accept any arguments, we can pass them at run time.  You are right.

Comment: @SidCool No problem, just wanted to make sure we were on the same page :) I think the correct way to say it is: this function has 0 **parameters**, but can obviously have any number of **arguments** (technically, like any Javascript function).

Answer (score 0):

For real-time replacements, I would use `onkeyup` to listen to whenever the user finishes pressing a key. Here's a JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kLTq5/1/